# command to find out what package manager installed this executable/file

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu, apt, which

I am looking for a script that would tell me what exactly installed a binary (or other asset) on a (Debianish) Linux system.

Nowadays there are so many package managers (snap, flatpak, pip, npm, composer, conda, brew, clib, cargo) besides apt*/rpm/manual that its a real hassle to find out what exactly installed what and more importantly: what package manager is supposed to keep it up to date.

#### Use cases

- These days its vital to distinguish between an app installed by the apt mechanism and something installed by snap
- When installing an app, one would prefer to find out if and what installed it before.

Comment: I would +1 this question except that it's written in a rather opinionated manner.

Comment: @Toby1Kenobi how about now? :)

Comment: "snap, flatpak, pip, npm, composer, conda, brew, clib, cargo" ... I think for all of these just inspecting the actual location of the executable will tell you (and probably better than a script can, since many of these have customizable install locations and the script will need to understand the configuration for all of those ... whereas you will likely recognise the paths on sight)